# Azure Devops Trigger a Pipeline from Multiple Stages of Other Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm trying to integrate a QA pipeline in Azure DevOps that triggers during a dev pipeline. The dev pipeline has 4 environments that the build is deploying to, where each environment is a stage in the dev pipeline

Currently, I'm able to trigger the QA builds for each environment using 4 separate QA pipelines using syntax similar to this in each pipeline:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: Dev_Env_1
    source: Dev
    trigger:
     stages:
       - Env_1
```

My goal is to only have one QA pipeline that is triggered multiple times by the dev pipeline when it completes each stage. It feels like syntax in the yml file like this should work:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: Dev_Env_1
    source: Dev
    trigger:
     stages:
       - Env_1

  - pipeline: Dev_Env_2
    source: Dev
    trigger:
     stages:
       - Env_2
```

However, this only triggers after Env_1 is completed, when I would like a build triggered for the completion of the Env_1 and Env_2 stages in the Dev pipeline.

Is there a way to do this without drastically changing the way either pipeline currently works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below steps can help you achieve your requirements.

For example,

**Dev Pipeline**

```
#Dev Pipeline
trigger:
- none
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

stages:
  - stage: Env_1
    displayName: Env_1
    jobs:
      - job:
        steps:
        - task: CmdLine@2
          inputs:
            script: |
              echo Stage1
  - stage: Env_2
    displayName: Env_2
    jobs:
      - job:
        steps:
        - task: CmdLine@2
          inputs:
            script: |
              echo Stage2
  - stage: Env_3
    displayName: Env_3
    jobs:
      - job:
        steps:
        - task: CmdLine@2
          inputs:
            script: |
              echo Stage3
  - stage: Env_4
    displayName: Env_4
    jobs:
      - job:
        steps:
        - task: CmdLine@2
          inputs:
            script: |
              echo Stage4
```

1, Create an incoming webhook service connection, and an incoming service webhook that is triggered by the complete and success of stages of the Dev Pipeline.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

incoming service hook URI: `https://dev.azure.com/<ADO Organization>/_apis/public/distributedtask/webhooks/<WebHook Name>?api-version=6.0-preview`

Official document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/pipelines/sprint-172-update#generic-webhook-based-triggers-for-yaml-pipelines

After that, write QA pipeline as below:

**QA Pipeline**

```
# QA pipeline

trigger:
- none

resources:
 webhooks:
   - webhook: bowmantest
     connection: BowmanIncommingWebHook


pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'


steps:
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      echo QA pipeline
```

Everything works fine:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]